# Xamarin Android not getting notification from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I create a new project using Navigation Drawer App (Android) template on Visual Studio 2017.

I followed the tutorial on [Remote Notifications With Fcm](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/data-and-cloud-services/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm/)

I can get the InstanceID token on debug log, but I did not get notification sent from Firebase console. (My app is on background, not foreground)

```
12-25 09:23:31.926 E/FirebaseInstanceId( 4331): Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement

12-25 09:23:31.926 E/FirebaseInstanceId( 4331): Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

Any suggestion?

P/S: Everything works just fine if I use Blank App (Android) template but not for Navigation Drawer App (Android) template

Comment: Have you register services ?

Comment: Yes. I have [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]

Comment: Have you register your `FirebaseMessagingService` ?

Comment: On navigation drawer app template, I have this error: package com.google.firebase.messaging does not exist
 extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService but I follow the same thing on blank app template, everything is working

Comment: Have you install the `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` nuget package?  Would you mind post more detailed codes? or maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo.

Comment: Yes. nuget package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging was installed. I uploaded to https://github.com/cwkhang/App1 - Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry for late, as a workaround you could copy the code from `Navigation Drawer App (Android) template` to your project.

Comment: Thanks! Copy the code from Navigation Drawer App (Android)  to Blank App template then everything works.